# How can I query a single value, at a certain time, from rrdtool?

Tags: rrdtool

It seems that rrdtool comes with functionality to query a range of values at a certain resolution. But can I simply query the value for a certain point in time? How?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes

```
rrdtool fetch -s $x -e $x+1 demo.rrd AVERAGE
```

will give you the values for a point in time.